# prime division problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

$a,b,c \in$ {0,1,2,...,9} with at least one of $a,b,c$ nonzero.  Prove that the six-digit integer $abcabc$ is divisible by at least 3 distinct primes.

My thinking is not to use induction as there is a definite size to the integer.

So $abcabc$ comes to $c1001 + b10010 + a100100$ with at least one of them nonzero.  This factors to $7^{1}11^{1}13^{1}c + 7^{1}11^{1}13^{1}2^{1}5^{1}b + 7^{1}11^{1}13^{1}2^{2}5^{2}a$ which factors to $7^{1}11^{1}13^{1}(c + 2^{1}5^{1}b + 2^{2}5^{2}a$) so with one of $a,b,c$ nonzero $abcabc$ is divisible by at least 3 primes $7,11,13$.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Did you just want verification, or was there more that you were trying to ask?

Comment: More briefly, $$(abc)(abc)=abc(1000+1)$$

Comment: @qaphla It just asked to prove it.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, Can you prove that? :)

Comment: @user2008730, Prove what?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, was just asking you to prove (abc)(abc)=abc(1000+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\overline{abcabc}=\overline{abc}(1001)$$
as:
$$\overline{abcabc}\\=10^5a+10^4b+10^3c+10^2a+10^1b+10^0c\\=10^2a(10^3+1)+10^1b(10^3+1)+10^0c(10^3+1)\\=(10^2a+10b+c)(10^3+1)$$
Since $1001$ is divisible by $7,11$ and $13$; you're done.

---

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: What do the * and line over abcabc mean?  Thanks.

Comment: @user2008730 if a=1,b=2,c=3, then $\overline{abc}=123$ just to avoid confusion with $abc=1\times2\times3=6$ and the asterik is just a refernce, i just removed it